# ErrorException (E_ERROR) Trying to get property 'title' of non-object - Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel 5.7, there is a relation that each student belongs to one program and I'm trying to get the specific student program title using `{{ $student->programs->title }}`

But there is an error

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View:D:\Work\UnitOne\BackEnd\UniLara\resources\views\admin\students\index.blade.php)

This is my **Student Mode**l

```
<?php

class Student extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'country', 'program_id', 'image'
    ];

    public function programs() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Program::class);
    }
}
```

and this is my **programs Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Program extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'description', 'image'
    ];

    public function students() {
        return $this->hasMany(Student::class);
    }
}
```

Here is my **StudentsController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\Students\CreateStudentsRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\Students\UpdateStudentsRequest;
use App\Program;
use App\Student;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class StudentsController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        return view('admin.students.index')->with('students', Student::paginate(5));
    }
}
```

and this is the last thing is the blade, Here's where I got the problem when I call `{{ $student->programs->title }}`

```
@foreach($students as $student)
    <tr>
        <td><img src="{{ asset($student->image) }}" alt="{{ $student->image }}"></td>
        <td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $student->country }}</td>
        <td>{{ student->programs->title }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Please submit your codes instead of sharing images.

Comment: at least one of your student is missing `program_id`. that is why you are getting this error. and don't share your code as an image. share the original code.

Comment: `$student->programs` meaning, that student has multiple programs. you have to loop through `$student->programs` or you have to do  `$student->programs->first()->title` to get the first program's title.

Comment: there is no any student that missed the `program_id` @zahidhasanemon

Comment: Sorry, I modified the question and added the code @RashedHasan

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran where i try `{{ $student->programs->first()->title }}` it shows **Call to a member function first() on null**

Comment: where you calling `$student->programs`. try this `$student->programs()->first()->title`. if still facing same issue, try `($student->programs) ? $student->programs->first()->title : ""'`

Comment: when i call `{{ $student->programs->first()->title }}` the error is **Call to a member function first() on null**
and when i call `{{ ($student->programs) ? $student->programs->first()->title : ""' }}` it shows Nothing !
@SandeepSudhakaran

Comment: meaning, that student have no programs. thats why its returning null. please update some programs to that particular student in you database and try the code. then it will show the result

Comment: actually each student has a one program in the database,
and the Answer by @zahidhasanemon is solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your relation name. Laravel looks for an column in the database like `relation_primarykey` if you don't specify a foreign key in the relationship definition. in your case your relation is `programs` but your database column is `program_id`. an extra `s` is causing the problem. So use either of the following.

```
public function program()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Program::class);
}
```

Or

```
public function programs()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Program::class, 'program_id');
}
```

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

Comment: Thanks @zahidhasanemon i changed the function name to
`public function program()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Program::class);
}` 
it Solve the problem and shows the specific student program as i want